# Tiling window management with Unity

Tags: unity, xmonad, tiling

EDIT: XMonad can be made to play well with Unity: http://markhansen.co.nz/xmonad-ubuntu-oneiric/ (thanks hvr)

I'm looking for a tiling window manager to use with Unity. I would like the manager to place all the windows for me, as XMonad does, though I get the impression XMonad doesn't play well with Unity. Unity does have some tiling features (you can use keyboard shortcuts to eg send a window to the left half of the screen), but this is still lacking compared to what I want, as I want the manager to choose where to place windows on my behalf. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it can do what you are asking but [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] can do many tricks and you might find an answer there.

By choosing **Place Windows** in **Windows Management** you are able to individually define a fixed location for windows:

[image]

Comment: It looks like this will allow me to statically define where certain classes of windows are placed, eg "Place Google Chrome windows on desktop 1", but won't let me rearrange windows easily on the fly. See this youtube video for what I'm trying to get: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyNkBLhIpQk